# What is the antonym for "waste/miss a chance"?

Tags: antonyms

Is there a verb that can replace "waste" in the original phrase to get the opposite meaning?
For instance, wouldn't it sound awkward if I say "I used all the chances I've been given"?

Comment: Can you give some context please?

Comment: _When opportunity knocked, I opened the door._

Comment: Thank you @J.R. , I know there are ways to express the idea differently, but I'm really wondering if there is a verb that can replace "waste" in the original phrase to get the opposite meaning?

Comment: Not that this answers your question but the awkwardness can be remedied by using a more parallel structure (I doubt that is proper English terminology) ie: "_I've_ used all the chances _I've_ been given." or more minimally "I used all the chances given" ( the explicit "having" removed in both places).  Both of these I think flow a bit better but the example sentence in the question is certainly functional.

Comment: 'Take a/your chance' works, but the expression 'take a chance' is ambiguous.

Comment: I have ***capitalized on*** every chance I’ve been given.

Comment: I have seized the day (from carpe diem).

Answer (score 2):

The two words that come to mind are *seize* or *grasp* an opportunity.  With the word *chance*, I think the most common verb would be *grab* or ‘*jump at*.

*Avail* has been suggested, and works.  You have to use it with a reflexive pronoun:  I avail *myself of* an opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

"Avail" is your word, or is pretty close. It means "to use or take advantage of (an opportunity or available resource)" (Google). But to use it you'd need to change your sentence slightly, because it acts on individuals that are phrased as objects. For example, *I availed myself of all opportunities.*

Comment: If you don't mention that you cited "Google" as a reference, then neither will I and hopefully nobody will notice.

Comment: I knew the word but I searched "define avail" and used the definition provided. Is this bad practice? Apparently Google gets their definitions from the Oxford American College Dictionary.